# Conditional Statements and Subsetting - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have the following dataset as ndarray:

```
print(predict)
[[[  7.03453398e+00   1.00585070e+01   5.34464791e-03   4.08430994e-02
     1.73265897e-02   1.48283215e-02  -1.95482448e-02  -5.05701825e-02
     8.75583757e-03   6.01415014e+00   7.04624176e+00   8.97313499e+00
    -1.38850473e-02  -6.31546229e-02   4.99860048e+00   6.01915455e+00 ...
```

I would like to update this set, printing **0**, **if** the value is **< 0**, and **round** each value.

How can I easily implement it in Python 3.?

Thanks

Comment: what did you have tried so far? how ever this is not evening here! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
new_pred = [int(pred) if pred > 0 else 0 for pred in np.nditer(predict)]
print(new_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it's an `ndarray`, I assume that numpy is allowed. Does this work for what you're looking for?

```
np.round(np.clip(predict, 0, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> One line solution:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[[  7.03453398e+00,   1.00585070e+01 ,  5.34464791e-03,   4.08430994e-02,
     1.73265897e-02,   1.48283215e-02,  -1.95482448e-02,  -5.05701825e-02,
     8.75583757e-03,   6.01415014e+00,   7.04624176e+00,   8.97313499e+00,
    -1.38850473e-02,  -6.31546229e-02,   4.99860048e+00,   6.01915455e+00]]])

print([0 if i<0 else int(i) for i in a[0][0] ])
```

> output:

```
[7, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 4, 6]
```

> Detailed solution:

Above list comprehensive is same as:

```
round=[]
for i in a[0][0]:
    if i<0:
        round.append(0)
    else:
        round.append(int(i))

print(round)
```